# What happens behind the scenes with $(element).each()?

Tags: jquery, loops

I have some code that is:

```
$('.someClass').each(function() {
    $(this).on(...);
});
```

and

```
$('.someClass').on(...);
```

What is happening behind the scenes with the first and second snippets of code? I noticed the second one works much faster and gives the same results as the first one.

Comment: when `$('.someClass')` has child elements you have to use `.each` to loop through children to perform any operation on it's children or any other related operation.Second will be simple `onclick` event for single HTML element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a simple line, `.on()` internally run the `.each()` function for event binding with given selector (as your code that is `.someClass`).

See snippet of `.on()`:

```
 on: function( types, selector, data, fn, /*INTERNAL*/ one ) {
    var type, origFn;

    // Types can be a map of types/handlers
    if ( typeof types === "object" ) {
        // ( types-Object, selector, data )
        if ( typeof selector !== "string" ) {
            // ( types-Object, data )
            data = data || selector;
            selector = undefined;
        }
        for ( type in types ) {
            this.on( type, selector, data, types[ type ], one );
        }
        return this;
    }

    if ( data == null && fn == null ) {
        // ( types, fn )
        fn = selector;
        data = selector = undefined;
    } else if ( fn == null ) {
        if ( typeof selector === "string" ) {
            // ( types, selector, fn )
            fn = data;
            data = undefined;
        } else {
            // ( types, data, fn )
            fn = data;
            data = selector;
            selector = undefined;
        }
    }
    if ( fn === false ) {
        fn = returnFalse;
    } else if ( !fn ) {
        return this;
    }

    if ( one === 1 ) {
        origFn = fn;
        fn = function( event ) {
            // Can use an empty set, since event contains the info
            jQuery().off( event );
            return origFn.apply( this, arguments );
        };
        // Use same guid so caller can remove using origFn
        fn.guid = origFn.guid || ( origFn.guid = jQuery.guid++ );
    }
    return this.each( function() {
        jQuery.event.add( this, types, fn, data, selector );
    });
}
```

So if you go through first snippet of your code ie. via calling `.on()` within `.each()` then `.on()` will run `.each()` for that element also itself.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, in the first snippet you are creating a separate jQuery object for each element in the result.  I'm guessing this has something to do with the additional time taken.